# Spring TransactionTemplate don't invoke commit on callback completion

Tags: java, spring

I'm using a TransactionTemplate with a anonymous TransactionCallback. At the end of the doInTransaction method the commit function of a custom PlatformTransactionManager is invoked.

I however want to delay this call until subsequent activities happen, thus delaying the commit until the correct place.

Is there a way to stop/tell the transaction template to not invoke the commit function and allow the transaction to "continue"?

Answer (score 0):

`@TransactionalEventListener` might help with the `BEFORE_COMMIT` hook.

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-event